# Query to check postgresql database status

Tags: postgresql

Is there any query to check the database status?
I just want to know if it is active or not on the remote host.So, Is there any query which return 200 OK if db is running and other db detail?

Comment: [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-isready.html)?

Comment: @Abelisto `select pg_isready from pg_stat_activity`
Are you implying this?

Comment: Follow the link provided. It is utility that checks is PostgreSQL server ready to receive connection requests. To execute a query you should to be able to connect to the server first which is impossible in case if the server is down. Probably I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-isready.html

```
-bash-4.2$ if pg_isready93 -d postgres://localhost:5432/template; then echo "200 OK"; else echo "500 NOT OK"; fi
200 OK
-bash-4.2$ if pg_isready93 -d postgres://localhost:5430/template; then echo "200 OK"; else echo "500 NOT OK"; fi
500 NOT OK
```

credits to Abelisto - I would not think of `pg_isready` in this context

Comment: BTW could be simplified like `(pg_isready -q -h 127.0.0.2 && echo Ok) || echo Fail` _"The exit status specifies the result of the connection check."_

Comment: PS Or using `if` statement: `if pg_isready -q -h 127.0.0.1; then echo Ok; else echo Fail; fi`

Comment: @Abelisto it is your answer - just edit it as you think it should be :)

Answer (score 5):

```
systemctl status postgresql
```

was what I was looking for